# JSONP callback is returning error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

I'm trying to learn JSONP. From my research online, I understood that it's invoke  function with callback.Apart from that everything else (the way data is handled/data format) similar to JSON?

I'm just playing with JSONP as below. But It's returning error, please explain in detail about it, please..

Script.js

```
function test(){
jQuery.ajax({
  url: "/plugins/system/chat/jsonstr.php",
  dataType: "jsonp",
  jsonpCallback: "logResults"
});
```

jsonstr.php

```
logResults(){
    $arr = '[{
        "title": "keren",
        "picture": "http://something.png",
        "id":1
    }, {
        "title": "diana",
        "picture": "/plugins/system/conversekit/conversekit/images/avatar.png",
        "id": 2
    }]';
    echo $arr;
}
```

I expect this call to return json object so that I can manipulate it in success function of test. But error as below is thrown:

```
<br />
<b>Parse error</b>:  syntax error, unexpected '{' in <b>C:\projects\easysocial.com\plugins\system\conversekit
\jsonstr.php</b> on line <b>14</b><br />
```

The url in console is as this:

```
GET http://mysite.localhost.com/plugins/system/chat/jsonstr.php?callback=logResults
```

Comment: `jsonpCallback: "logResults"` ==> `jsonpCallback: logResults`

Comment: `echo $arr;` ==> `echo json_encode($arr);`

Comment: @Tushar, jsonpCallback: logResults, says "ReferenceError: logResults is not defined"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

logResults() is JavaScript callback, not PHP function. jsonstr.php should only return valid JSON.

So jsonstr.php should look like this

```
<?php

 $arr = [
            [
                'title' => "keren",
                'picture' => "http://something.png",
                'id' => 1,
            ],
            [
                'title' => "diana",
                'picture' => "/plugins/system/conversekit/conversekit/images/avatar.png",
                'id' => 2,
            ],
        ];

echo(json_encode($arr));
```

And Script.js

```
function logResults() {
    console.log('ajax done');
}

function test(){
    jQuery.ajax({
      url: "/plugins/system/chat/jsonstr.php",
      dataType: "jsonp",
      jsonpCallback: logResults
    });
}
```

Comment: If I wanna use jsonstr.php as an API, I will define multiple functions..So how do I call particular function via jsonp?

Comment: You can use GET parameters, like `/plugins/system/chat/jsonstr.php?method=get_users`. You can add any logic to your PHP, but in the end return JSON.

Comment: In PHP you can find GET like this `$_GET['method']`

Comment: may I know why the callback function doesnt do anything?

Comment: I edited Script.js in the answer. It should work like this, although I didn't test it.

Comment: I changed the files just like yours, and it works but I should be able to do something with the json data returned. So i did this but it says undefined for data value:function logResults(data) {
    console.log('ajax done'+data);
}

Comment: There is method done() available in jQuery, it will be easier with it. `jQuery.ajax({
      url: "/plugins/system/chat/jsonstr.php",
      dataType: "jsonp",
    }).done(function (data) {                      
                    alert('ajax done');              
             });`

Answer (score 1):

Two issues:

1. Your server-side script doesn't return anything, as the *Net* pane in your browser developer tools should reveal.
2. JSONP is just a dirty trick to avoid cross-site permission issues in AJAX, not a way to make PHP code interact with JavaScript (something that is not possible). So when you say "I want a callback function called *logResults*" you mean a **JavaScript** function.

If you want to use JSONP you need:

1. Make your server actually return JSONP (not even JSON):

   ```
   $callback = filter_INPUT(INPUT_GET, 'callback');
   // ...
   echo sprintf('%s(%s);', $callback, $json);
   ```
2. Define a JavaScript function to process the returned data:

   ```
   function logResults (data) {
       alert(data[0].title);
   }
   ```

This way you basically get a dynamically generated good old `<script>` tag that loads a simple script:

```
logResults([{
        "title": "keren",
        "picture": "http://something.png",
        "id":1
    }, {
        "title": "diana",
        "picture": "/plugins/system/conversekit/conversekit/images/avatar.png",
        "id": 2
    }]);
```

But since you are making an AJAX call in your own domain:

```
url: "/plugins/system/chat/jsonstr.php",
     ^^
      No "http://example.com/` prefix pointing to a third-party site
```

... you **don't need JSONP at all**: plain JSON will be enough.

Comment: Alvaro you're right, my server script doesn't return anything, thus the logResults function is not doing what it supposed to do. I only see the response in the console. I tried your answer t invoke the callback but to no avail

Comment: @Keren I've completely revamped my question after (hopefully) understanding where the confusion comes from.

Comment: Oh... I was just doing some cleanup because I assumed you had it sorted out (you've tagged an answer as accepted). **Parse error** means that your PHP code doesn't have a valid syntax and can't even run.

Comment: Thanks a lot Alvaro, I opt to use JSON/notmal ajax call instaed of jsonp